# Game help please

Tags: combinatorics

I partake in a fantasy football game where it's possible work out a players monitary values using the stats provided but I seem unable to find the correct equation to work out how to correctly do this.

Here is an example:

Name - 'Player A' 
Age - 23
foot - Right footed
Shooting - 7
Movement - 6
Passing - 9
Control - 8
Speed - 9
Stamina - 8
Heading - 7
Strength - 8
Aggresion - 8
Tackling - 9
Judgement - 6
Vision - 5
Overall - 90
value - 15,212,960

now obviously I can see all the stats added together equal 90 hence why overal rating in 90 (maximum each individual stat can go to is 10). The only other information I have to go on is his 'positional value' which is 34 (this is the players value in his best position comprised by adding together his control, passing, speed and stamina... 9,8,9,8 = 34).

apparantly there is a way to work his value of 15,212,960 by doing an math equation using the stats I've mentioned but I can't get near it... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do if you give only a single player, you can only guess. If the price is a linear function of individual stats, you would need at least 14 players to find the equation.

In a game the price should be dependant at least on price, overall and positional stats. You should try to check if other players with the same age, same position and same overall value and positional value (but different individual stats like passing or stamina) also have the same price? Or they have different prices?

You must first find out on which stats the price actually depends. Then you must find a bit more players than the "valuable" stats. and then come back here for further help when you have the data.

Generally I would approach this problem by choosing a bunch of players with the same age. Then I'd check if there exist coefficients $a$ and $b$ such that 
$$Price = a * Pos.Val + b$$ 
If not - maybe it's the same equation but for overall value? If not, then try equations 
$$Price = a*Pos.Val^2 + b*Pos.Val + c$$ and $$Price = a*b^{Pos.Val}+c$$

It's unlikely that a game would use some high-power, logarithmic or triganometrical equations for such dependancies, so if these doesn't work, the dependancy has to be more complex, like
$$Price = a*Pos.Val + b*Ov.Val + c$$

And so on you just check equations of more and more complex form until you find the right one.

Comment: Unfortunately all of the players in my team are all different and no two have similar statistics. I have noticed that the positional value and untrainable values seem to be the most valuable. Untrainables in the game are stats that can't improve which are speed, aggression, judgement and vision. Would it help if I added a few more players on here for you to view and compare?

Comment: Yes, if you gave more data, I (or someone else) could give it a shot. Are you familiar with solving systems of linear equations yourself?

Comment: Not in the slightest but I love to learn! Ok here a few players for you, hope it helps in finding the equation!

Comment: Player 1 - 28(age), 6,9,8,7,9,9,6,7,9,8,7,6 - 91 overall, 35 position value (movement,passing, speed, stamina), 31 untrainable stat value - 15,820,057 cash value

Comment: Player 2 - 25(age), 7,6,8,6,4,7,7,9,5,9,9,6 - 83 overall, 34 positional value(strength, heading, tackling, judgement), 24 untrainable stat - 5,442,042 cash value.

Comment: Player 3 - 23(age), 7,6,9,8,8,4,6,7,4,6,8,9 - 82 overall, 34 positional value (passing, control, judgement, vision), 29 untrainable value - 5,504,927

Comment: Player 4 - 20(age), 9,8,7,7,9,7,4,4,9,4,7,8 - 83 overall, 33 positional value(shooting, movement, control,speed), 33 untrainable value - 3,235,357 cash value

Comment: The only thing I will add is I noticed the older a player gets the lower his cash value gets